# Not show reserved cars and show cars that are not reserved

Tags: mysql

o/

So I am working on a rental page for a school project and can't figure out what to do next. :/ So the function's I need to implement are that it should display cars that don't have a reservation yet. As seen below

```
SELECT * FROM reservering 
            INNER JOIN auto 
                ON auto_id = kenteken 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM auto
                WHERE kenteken = auto_id
                )
```

It doesn't return a value not sure what I did wrong really. And the not displaying a car that has a reservation see code below:

```
SELECT * FROM reservering 
            INNER JOIN auto 
                ON auto_id = kenteken 
            INNER JOIN merktype 
                ON merktype_id = id
            WHERE auto_id AND ophaaldatum NOT BETWEEN '2022-05-05' AND '2022-05-05' OR retourdatum NOT BETWEEN '2022-05-05' AND '2022-05-07'
```

Right now it shows the same car multiple times because the same car already has a reservation in the future. I want it to just not display if it already has reservation between the time I am searching for otherwise I will have duplicated reservations on the same day.

Any help will be appreciated take care o>

Answer (score 0):

Your main query should be from `auto`, not `reservering`. Then you should test whether there's a corresponding row in `reservering`.

```
SELECT *
FROM auto AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM reservering AS r
    WHERE r.auto_id = a.kenteken
)
```

or using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT a.*
FROM auto AS a
LEFT JOIN reservering AS r ON r.auto_id = a.kenteken
WHERE r.auto_id IS NULL
```

See [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1)

Comment: Will this make the car have multiple reservations and also the auto doesn't have reservering as foreign key so will it still work?

Comment: This only returns cars that have no reservations. It uses the `auto_id` foreign key in the `reservering` table. You don't need a foreign key the other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "make the car have multiple reservations"? `SELECT` doesn't change anything, it's just returning what's already there. If the card doesn't have any reservations, how can there be multiple reservations?

Comment: Thank you :D it now shows cars that don't have a reservation yet problem is that it still displays cars even if it has a reservation it shows the future reservations of the same car it doesn't display 

`SELECT a.*, mt.*, r.*
FROM auto AS a
LEFT JOIN merktype AS mt ON a.merktype_id = mt.id
LEFT JOIN reservering AS r ON r.auto_id = a.kenteken
WHERE ophaaldatum  NOT BETWEEN '$insertedOphaaldatum' AND '$insertedRetourdatum' AND (r.retourdatum  NOT BETWEEN '$insertedOphaaldatum' AND '$insertedRetourdatum') 
OR (r.auto_id IS NULL)`

Comment: Please post sample data and the desired result. Post it as plain text so I can copy and paste into the test environment.