# Calculate overlap between two tables on two columns

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have two tables, T1 and T2, with exact same columns: `ClientId` and `ItemId`.

I want to calculate: for each `ClientId` in T2, how many `ItemId`s exist in T2 but not in T1.

Example:

T1

| ClientId | ItemId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 21 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 23 |

T2

| ClientId | ItemId |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 2 | 24 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | 31 |

Expected Output

| ClientId | ItemIdCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Explanation:

In `T2`, for `ClientId=2`, we have four `ItemIds`: 22, 23, 24, 25. However, this same client ID in T1 has two of those values: 22, 23. Thus, the `ItemIdCount` for this client ID is two.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1 for how to get all the rows in T2 that aren't in T1. Then use `COUNT(*) GROUP BY ClientID` to get the row counts.

Comment: @Barmar but that would give me only the count of `ItemID`s for each `ClientId` that exists in T2 but not in T1. But I also would like to exclude all the `ItemId`s in T1 for that `ClientId` and then do the count.

Comment: "only the count of ItemIDs for each ClientId that exists in T2 but not in T1" That's exactly what you said in the question.

Comment: Please update the question with sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer here, but what you quoted above is not what I have in my question. It exactly says "for each ClientId in T2, how many ItemIds exist in T2 but not in T1". @Barmar

Comment: I still don't understand the difference. That's why I asked you to post an example in the question.

Comment: @Barmar added some example values, hope this clarifies what I am trying to ask.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uN8rA33mzinf5Q6JRcMg6d/0