# How to use join for DELETE clause in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have the following query:

```
delete from customers_cards
where id not in (
    select min(id)
     from customers_cards
     group by number_card )
and belongs_to = "ezpay"
```

It throws:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'customers_cards' for update in FROM clause

I guess I need to use `join` as a workaround, but honestly, I cannot rewrite the same logic with join. Any idea how can I write the query above with `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join should be similar to what you would use to [select rows in one table but not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1)

```
DELETE c1 
FROM customers_cards AS c1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id
    FROM customer_cards
    GROUP BY number_card
) AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.id
WHERE c2.id IS NULL AND c1.belongs_to = 'ezpay'
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, just should I put `belongs_to = "ezpay"` inside the parentheses or outside?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method:

Delete any row `c1` that belongs to 'ezpay', provided another row `c2` exists with the same `number_card` and a lesser `id`.

```
DELETE c1
FROM customer_cards AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers_cards AS c2
  ON c1.number_card = c2.number_card AND c1.id > c2.id
WHERE c2.id IS NOT NULL AND c1.belongs_to = 'ezpay';
```