# Sql Query: Return the where condition that not available in database

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm new and trying to learn query! I wonder if it possible to get result/ return value of the where condition if none of the conditions are exist in the database, so I can differentiate which conditions exist and not in database!

For example:

```
 Select *
 From Student
 Where Student.id IN ("1","2","3")
```

The Result I expect is if the id of 2 is not exist in database, then I will get the result of 2. Hence, i will know that id 2 is not yet exist in database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a technique similar to finding a row in a table that doesn't have a match in another table, as described in [Return row only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1)

But since you're comparing with a list rather than a table, you have to synthesize a table from that list. You can do that with a subquery or CTE.

```
WITH id_list AS (
    SELECT "1" AS id
    UNION
    SELECT "2"
    UNION
    SELECT "3"
)
SELECT id_list.id 
FROM id_list
LEFT JOIN Student ON id_list.id = Student.id
WHERE Student.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply! What if i have lot of ids? Is there a way for that, or it would be better to put all those ids in a table and compare it between table? Thanks

Comment: Yes, create a temporary table with this information.