Select random elements excluding given range and not starting with same word
I have a "foods" table containing foods:



id
name




1
pasta with meat


2
pasta with cheese


3
ice cream


4
salad chicken


5
noodles


6
salad tuna



and a "weeks" table containing the last meals eaten (the food id's).
I generate with success a random menu for the next week dinners, different from the last week one, with:
SELECT `id` 
FROM `foods` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN (1,5,19,13,26,2,7) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7;

The excluded id's (1,5,19,13,26,2,7) are taken from the table "weeks" last row (id's of foods eaten last week).
Now I would like to generate the menu but not with the same kind of food:
I mean, having in the foods table "pasta with meat" and "pasta with cheese", I do not want to eat "pasta" two days in the same week, and also all id's have to be different from last week.
I insert the foods in the table starting with the same first word to have a usable pattern like "pasta with meat", "pasta with cheese" etc.
Thank you in advance for your help.
EDIT:
Thank you very much for your help and revision, I know I would just need to categorize the foods, but I needed to know if it could be possible to do it with my bare 2 tables, because I already have a php page set and I do not know how to categorize all the different foods I will insert, to categorize is too strict for me.
I just need to avoid having duplicates starting with the same word.
Usually I store queries results in PHP variables, and then use them as parameters to go on with subsequent queries, but in this case I wanted to understand if it was possible to achieve the result in one query or using subqueries.
My idea was somthing like: get all foods, in case of "same initial word" get randomly only one of that kind, then use this result to get randomly 7 ids NOT IN the already eaten.
Thanks again for your help and time.

Can you redesign the table? It would be better to have a column with just the first word, so you can easily exclude them with a join.

Would be much better and easier if same food had the same id, for example pasta with meat and pasta with cheese would have id 1, is it possible to fix the design ?

Anyway, use a subquery or CTE to get the items eaten in the current and previous week. Then use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633115/return-row-only-if-value-doesnt-exist?lq=1 to exclude them in the result.

To get the first word, use SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1).

Îf you want to categorise food, use a related table food_category, and have each record in  the foods table link to it. Select foods that have different food_category_id,  Never make queries that work on substrings if you can do relational databases properly.
table food
id  name                category_id
1   pasta with meat         1
2   pasta with cheese       1
3   ice cream               2
4   salad chicken           3
5   noodles                 1
6   salad tuna              3


table food_category
id  category
1   pasta/noodles
2   desert
3   salad

Now we need two queries: one to randomize the food categories, and one to randomize the foods within the category. This is how you put those two together. The LIMIT is to limit for 7 days.
SELECT random_food.* 
FROM food_category 
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM food ORDER BY rand() ) AS random_food
  ON category_id = food_category.id
GROUP BY food_category.id
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 7 

If you want to not have things you had last week and you have that in a log, make sure you have a table with the food per day instead of per week so you can do it like this:
table eaten
id  date       food_id
1   2024/10/04  1
2   2024/10/05  5
3   2024/10/06  19

etc.
It then becomes:
SELECT random_food.* 
 FROM food_category 
     JOIN (SELECT * FROM food 
           WHERE food.id NOT IN (SELECT food_id 
                                 FROM eaten 
                                 WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
           ORDER BY rand() ) AS random_food
     ON category_id = food_category.id
GROUP BY food_category.id
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 7

Or if you insist on having the id's of food items eaten last week in a string (don't) of the last record of the table weeks:
 table weeks

 id  week year eaten_food_ids
 1    31  2024 "1,5,19,13,26,2,7"

it then becomes
 SELECT random_food.* 
 FROM food_category 
     JOIN (SELECT food.* 
           FROM food 
               JOIN weeks ON weeks.id = (SELECT MAX(weeks.id) FROM weeks) 
           WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(food.id, weeks.eaten_food_ids) 
           ORDER BY rand() ) AS random_food
     ON category_id = food_category.id
GROUP BY food_category.id
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 7;

In all queries the workings are as follow:
The outer SELECT selects a random category. You don't want twice the same category in a week, you wrote, so that is guaranteed this way.
The inner SELECT selects all foods in random orders (except for last week's).
By joining the 7 random categories (outer select) with the randomised food (inner select) list you have exactly what you want. We GROUP BY category because we want one category per day.
In general, if you are a beginner, start to learn to separate different categories of information into different tables. In the beginning you will add too much information into a table, many information that should have its own table. That's normal, it's the nature of learning relational databases, but it is disastrous for maintenance and efficiency. Keep it is simple and very clear. A short youtube video on the basics of relation databases may help you a lot and save you a LOT of time and struggle.
NOTE: based on the discussion below I added a new solution using more appropriate techniques. Both work, but this is more as MySQL was intended.
SELECT name, category_id 
FROM (
   SELECT food.*, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY RAND()) AS row_number
   FROM food
) RandomFood
WHERE row_number = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 7;

To add the restriction of last week you can add it in there:
SELECT name, category_id FROM (
    SELECT food.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY RAND()) AS row_number
    FROM food 
    JOIN weeks ON weeks.id = (SELECT MAX(weeks.id) FROM weeks) 
    WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(food.id, weeks.eaten_food_ids) 
) RandomFood
WHERE row_number = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 7;


That's what Google gave me when I tried it in a sandbox and got that error (never had it before). Instead of downvoting, why don't you a) say WHY it is not a good idea, b) edit the solution to improve it or add a comment how to improve it? Just downvoting without adding anything to the solution is not what this forum is about.

That's what Google gave does not justify giving wrong suggestions. Setting sql_mode to empty does a lot of damage. One of them is allowing invalid query running , such as  those with the error in the Note section, if sql_mode , only_full_group_by is enabled.  I can not edit the answer because it will change a lot from the original. It is up to you to edit

Not gonna lie, you seem here just to be negative. No, my suggestion -- to resolve a POSSIBLE problem -- was not false: it worked. It was apparently dangerous. That is a different thing and an EXTREMELY important distinction. You just added confusion. But even that danger was only for the current session, which in most cases is not a problem. Also, a solution was VERY easy to edit and  did NOT change the original solution at all. You can check it as the sql_mode-expert here, but please, if you find anything wrong again: remember this platform is not for grumping but for helping. Really.

It seems that you are missing the point here. After the edit you are saying to remove only_full_group_by which I am strongly recommend to not do, because the retrieved data result would be arbitrary. I am not interested on feelings , but on what the OP or future readers will gain from this answers.

Are you saying that arbitrary results are not the same as the random results? This could be, for me it works wherever I tested. If that is the case, why not say so in the first place?

Arbitrary <> Random. That's why you are missing my point. In this example you don't know which data will be retrieved for col2 . Sometimes it might be foo sometimes bar for val1 etc. In such cases col2 must be part of the group by clause or part of an aggrtegatie function on the select list

Since we want random data, your example doesn't make much of a point. The only two points you can actually have, at least that I can think of, are that despite the ORDER BY rand() you get the same values every time. I have never seen that, but theoretically that could be possible. Another point is of course that "if you know what you do you can use GROUP BY this way" is not the best way to teach beginners. I do agree with that.
I added a solution that is more appropriate at the end. I have no clue which one is more efficient.


the same or non-randomised

