# Null values in IN clause - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Here is my Table1

```
personid
1
?
2
3
4
?
6
```

---

Here is my query

```
select * 
from table2
where personid not in 
(
select personid
from table1
)
```

The result is `nothing`

---

Here is my second query

```
select * 
from table2
where personid not in 
(
select personid
from table1         
where personid is not null
)
```

The result is `ok`

---

Question : why the first query did not work ? I can't see any logical problem . Do `null`s skrew up teradata ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not specific to Teradata, it's the same (or at least should be the same) in all RDBMSes. Any comparison to a NULL results in UNKNOWN and NOT IN is an ANDed condition:

personid <> 1st_value_in_list AND personid <> 2nd_value_in_list AND ... **AND personid <> NULL**

This has been discussed multiple times, e.g. 
[NOT IN clause and NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If one of the value in the subquery is NULL, the IN clause does not return anything.