# Null value in column resulting into no output in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables (`stud` and `stud1`). Both having 2 columns but `stud1` contains 1 record which is null.

[image: data from query]

I have created following 2 queries.First one is returning the accurate result but other one which is using not in returning nothing. I guess that is because of the null value. But I don't understand the reason for it. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Were you expecting *3 India* to appear for your second query?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [NOT IN clause and NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values).

That's because your 2nd query equals:

```
SELECT * FROM #stud
WHERE ID <> NULL
```

When `ansi_nulls` is on, `ID <> NULL` is unknown, so you won't get any rows.