# Why doesn't this query work

Tags: sql, sql-server, notin

There are two tables, both have only one column. 
`delete_DimCSI` has 196194 rows and `delete_FRO` has 195740 rows. I am looking for rows that exist in `delete_DimCSI` table but not existing in `delete_FRO` table.

This is the query I usually use and it worked so far:

```
select PK_CSI from delete_DimCSI
where PK_CSI not in (select FK_CSI from delete_FRO)
```

It returns 0 rows.

Then I created this one:

```
select PK_CSI, FK_CSI from delete_DimCSI
LEFT OUTER JOIN delete_FRO FRO on FK_CSI = PK_CSI
where FK_CSI is null
```

It returns 455 rows.

Any idea why the first query doesn't return any row?

Comment: I guess because the second query joins both tables on that column and select all where the foreign-key is null or there is no row with that `PK_CSI`. The first query uses `NOT IN` which ignores NULL values. Instead i prefer `NOT EXISTS`. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: possible duplicate of [NOT IN clause and NULL values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have `NULL`s in `FK_csi`

```
select PK_CSI from delete_DimCSI
where PK_CSI not in (select FK_CSI from delete_FRO WHERE FK_CSI IS NOT NULL)
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129152/1745672) for an explanation.

Comment: true... you just reminded me I had this issue few years ago :)

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` behaves strangely when the subquery has `NULL` values.  In that case, it returns either `NULL` or false -- neither of which is treated as true.

For this reason, I recommend using `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`.  The semantics are more what you expect:

```
select PK_CSI
from delete_DimCSI d
where not exists (select 1 from delete_FRO f where f.FK_CSI = d.PK_CSI);
```

Of course, you can also add an explicit `where`f.FK_CSI = NULL` as Mihai suggests.