# Why different results for "not in" in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join, notin

I would like to know how many serial numbers appear in table 2 but not in table 1. When I run:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT sn)
FROM table2
WHERE sn NOT IN (table1.sn)
```

I get 0.

I am certain there exist serial numbers in table2 not in table1, luckily when I run:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT sn)
FROM table2
WHERE sn NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT table1.sn
FROM(
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON(table1.sn=table2.sn)
) 
)
```

I get a large number of sn's.

This is not logically possible!
It means there are serial numbers in table 2 not in the join, but there are no serial numbers in table 2 not in table 1. 
I tried casting the results from the query & sub query to text and that didn't work.

Comment: `WHERE NOT IN (table1.sn)` is invalid SQL. I guess you didn't show us the real query. But the reason for this behaviour are most probably `NULL` values in that column

Comment: Please refer to "NOT IN clause and NULL values"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values

Comment: Sorry, I meant WHERE sn NOT IN...I checked and there are no NULLs in the sn column

Comment: Then please *edit* your question to fix it. And provide table definitions and your version of Postgres while being at it.

Comment: Got it! indeed the problem was NULL's in table 1. Thanks!!!