# SQL - records not in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In doing what I thought was a fairly routine task of finding records in one table that do not exist in another table, I started out like the following. Note: the common value is of type float in one table (thus the cast) and varchar(20) in the other. MEMID=float, DMID=varchar.

```
select cast((convert(int, MEMID)) as varchar(20))
from tempProv111315
where cast((convert(int, MEMID)) as varchar(20)) NOT IN (
     SELECT DMID
     FROM tempMemberMaster121015
)
```

The above returned no records (even though i knew a few existed). Therefore I tried the following (which worked).

```
select cast((convert(int, pv.MEMID)) as varchar(20))
from tempProv111315 pv
left outer join  tempMemberMaster121015 mm on
   cast((convert(int, pv.MEMID)) as varchar(20)) = mm.dmid
where mm.dmid is null
```

Although likely a simple reason, for the life of me I cannot see why the first way didn't work. I'm not a dba but have used both ways often in different circumstances so I really want to understand what I'm missing. Can anyone explain the different outcome as they ***seem*** logically equal to me.

ps - i'm familiar with several ways to cast the float. This is my typical method. I don't believe it is the issue... but if so, why does it work okay on the second statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly useful reading: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a known behavior, your sub-query would have returned `NULL` which makes the `not in` to fail. More info can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values?rq=1)

```
NOT IN
(
     SELECT DMID -- check whether this returns any NULL value
     FROM tempMemberMaster121015
)
```

I will suggest you to use `NOT EXIST` instead of `Left Outer Join`

Comment: Correct, there is a single null in the return. Combined with the 'useful reading' AHiggins provided above in the comment, i now get it. Your suggestion to use 'not exists' is appropriate and what I intend to do. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) query in SQL Server to return distinct rows from the results of one query that are not in the results of a second query.

The syntax is:

```
{ <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) } 
EXCEPT 
{ <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) }
```

An example using the tables/queries in your question:

```
SELECT CAST((CONVERT(INT, MEMID)) AS VARCHAR(20)) from tempProv111315  
EXCEPT
SELECT DMID FROM tempMemberMaster121015
```

Note: for other database systems: In Oracle the keyword is [MINUS](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Minus) instead of EXCEPT. In MySQL there is no EXCEPT operator and I don't believe PostgreSQL does either. However Gokhan Atil has a post describing [how to implement the behavior of EXCEPT](http://www.gokhanatil.com/2010/10/minus-and-intersect-in-mysql.html), which incidentally is the same as the LEFT OUTER JOIN query that you found success with in your question.

Comment: Very nice! I just tried this and it works beautifully. MM93 fully answered the question but this may be the way I go unless I find a downside. thanks for the great suggestion.