# Understanding Django queryset field lookup in

Tags: python, django-queryset

Short version: Why does Model.objects.exclude(..__in=[None]) exclude every object?

I have encountered an interesting behaviour of django field lookup that I do not understand. Let's say I have 21 objects of a given model:

```
>>> Model.objects.count()
21
```

If I exclude a given private key directly or with `in` field lookup I get the expected behaviour:

```
>>> Model.objects.exclude(pk=1).count()
20
>>> Model.objects.exclude(pk__in=[1]).count()
20
```

If I exclude the private key of value `None` I get the expected result:

```
>>> Model.objects.exclude(pk=None).count()
21
```

However if I do the same with the `in` field lookup I get nothing back:

```
>>> Model.objects.exclude(pk__in=[None]).count()
0
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because of the way SQL treats NULL. The query compiles to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mymodel WHERE NOT (id IN (NULL));`.

See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values) for a discussion of why NOT IN with NULL always returns empty.

Comment: Good one. Most likely the case. Didn't know about `connection.queries`