# NULL value not coming as part of query even after condition satisfying

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am having simple query to get all classes which is not 'RS' in hive. My data looks like as follows

```
Account                 class
3000337430920208808     NULL
3000337394422514891     NULL
3000337317010916590     NULL
3000337153318453626     NULL
3000337129720896321     NULL
```

I have written query as

```
select account_number,service_class from cdx_eligibility where   account_number='3000337430920208808' and service_class not in ('RS');
```

I am not getting output as this account. Ideally NULL <> RS (so its true and should return record). But i am not getting any records. Do we need to handle NULLS in different way? I also tried several options (!=,<>,not in). Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Hive issue, this is how SQL works.  When you compare 'RS' to `null`, it doesn't return anything, not true or false. You can't do `'foo' = null` either. This is one reason why allowing nulls in character fields is a pain. If you have to have null values, then use

`where coalesce(service_class,'') not in ('RS')`.

That way you're comparing an empty string to 'RS', which works as you'd expect it to.

Comment: Thanks..the database has nulls and it is unavoidable.so this piece of code works for Number datatype also. Right?

Answer (score 0):

looks like hive can't handle properly null values for "in" clauses, this workaround should work

```
select account_number,service_class from cdx_eligibility where   account_number='3000337430920208808' and (isnull(service_class ) or service_class not in ('RS'));
```