# Find deleted rows: Not EXISTS vs Not IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my case, I have two table with same structure: `TableA` & `TableB`, and what I was trying to do is to find if there is any records only exists in A but not B.

My script was

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TableB
)
```

While there is 2 records which only exists in A but not B, this script returns nothing. Then I changed into following:

```
SELECT ID FROM TableA
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM TableB
)
```

This script works successfully and return the 2 records' ID.

---

My question is: Is this behavior normal? What is the mechanism behind `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`?

I have read some other posts comparing `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`, and most people suggest using `NOT EXISTS` in 99.9% scenarios, is this case fall into that 0.1% which `NOT EXISTS` is not applicable? *(I believed it's due to my wrongly usage though, please correct me if that's the case)*

Comment: The first query lacks the condition, like `WHERE TableB.id = TableA.id` (inside the nested query). So then the query literally is read as: select everything from TableA where the row from TableB with the same id does not exist.

Comment: "is this case fall into that 0.1% which NOT EXISTS is not applicable" --- I would say that **every** query with `IN` might be expressed with `EXISTS`. The opposite is not true though (is it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to look at all the values in the rows, then use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM TableB;
```

If you want to use `NOT EXISTS` correctly, then you need a correlation clause:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.id = a.id);
```

I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN` with a subquery.  `NOT IN` will return no rows at all if `b.id` is *ever* `NULL`.  That is usually not what is intended.  `NOT EXISTS` matches the expected semantics.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why `NOT IN` ever existed if `NOT EXISTED` is a super set in usage as @zerkms mentioned...

Comment: @shole . . . First, they have different semantics (subtle differrence, but different).  Second, `NOT IN` works with constant lists.  Third, SQL does not claim to do things only one way.  There are other methods including `<> ALL` and a `left join`.  That's just how the language was designed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with the `NOT IN` expression.
The `A NOT IN(B,C,D)` expression basically means `(A<>B AND A<>C AND A<>D)`. If any of the values are NULL the whole expression will become NULL.

So, applicable to your example the correct NOT IN expression should be (unless the ID is not nullable column):

```
SELECT ID FROM TableA
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM TableB WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found this post which makes things more clear to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values