# Django QuerySet.exclude(): Why are all excluded?

Tags: python, django

I have a situation like this:

```
ids = [None, None, None]
foo = Foo.objects.filter(common=True).exclude(id__in=ids)
```

This seems to exclude all always.

Why is `id` of `id__in` threated as `None` in this case? `pk__in` didn't work either. I expect it to not exclude anything as all objects have valid id's.

```
foo = Foo.objects.filter(common=True)
```

Returns all objects like expected.

Comment: `None` gets converted to sql NULL in the query, and then the db does something weird.  The primary key should never be `None` anyway, so what are you actually trying to query here??

Comment: I'm just trying to exclude objects by id and the exclusion list may contain None's. It's irrelevant here.

Comment: Pre-filter the exclusion list not to contain None's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your queryset will generate SQL similar to `select * from foo where NOT (id in (NULL));`

In SQL both `x in (NULL)` and `NOT (x in (NULL))` evaluate to `null`, so the query returns no rows. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values) for more info.

The solution, as @wim pointed out in the comments, is to filter out the `None` values from the list:

```
foo = Foo.objects.filter(common=True).exclude(id__in=[x for x in ids if x is not None])
```