# SQL NOT IN function not returning expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Total number of records in table i1450:

[image]

Total number with condition where `i.BROJ` is equal to field `REFERENCA` in other table:

[image]

Shouldn't it return difference between last two results (which is 64) when I use `NOT IN` in `WHERE` clause?

[image]

Both of columns are of `varchar` type.

Comment: Any REFERENCA null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any `NULL` values in the `REFERENCA` column from the `FpsPmtOrderRQ` table then the `NOT IN` clause will not work as expected - ([the reason why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values))

A solution is to remove `NULL` values from the result returned by the subselect.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM i1450 j
WHERE i.BROJ NOT IN (SELECT REFERENCA FROM FpsPmtOrderRQ WHERE REFERENCA IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Will it count those records in 1st table in `BROJ` where value is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

If the sub-query returns a null value, the `IN` will not be true. Do `NOT EXISTS` instead.

```
select count(*)
from i1450 i
where not exists (select 1 from FpsPmtOrderRQ f
                  where i.broj = f.REFERENCA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to coalesce your field to handle nulls. That is probably why you get 0. 
By doing:

```
where coalesce(I.BROJ,'n/a') not in (select coalesce(REFERENCA,'')
```

or something similar, you would exclude nulls, and return a proper count.

Comment: It's better to simply skip the null rows. (As Radu's answer.)