# SQL Server join where not exist on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

```
+-------------------+   +-------------------+   +---------------------+
|      Service      |   |       Asset       |   |     AssetService    |
+-------------------+   +-------------------+   +---------------------+
| Id   |    Name    |   | Id   |    Name    |   | AssetId | ServiceId |
|-------------------|   |-------------------|   |---------------------|
| 1    |  Service 1 |   | 1    |   Asset 1  |   |     1   |     1     |
| 2    |  Service 2 |   | 2    |   Asset 2  |   |     1   |     2     |
| 3    |  Service 3 |   | 3    |   Asset 3  |   |     2   |     2     |
+-------------------+   +-------------------+   |     2   |     3     |
                                                +---------------------+
```

So I have these tables. I want to get the `Services` that is not on `AssetService` where `AssetId = 1`
Like this:

```
+-------------------+
|      Service      |
| Id   |    Name    |
+-------------------+
| 3    |  Service 3 |
+-------------------+
```

Is this possible with just inner/left/right join? because I already tried different combinations of inner join but it's not working, like this `inner join Asset a on a.Id != as.AssetId`. I event tried left and right join.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't possible to do with just inner joins. If a Service has no rows in AssetService then the inner join will remove it from the result but it must be returned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest I can think of:

```
select * from Service
where Id not in (
    select ServiceId
    from AssetService 
    where AssetId = 1);
```

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2344c/1)

I don't think it's possible using `inner join`, because that would only retrieve records that match some criteria and you are looking for records that do *not* match.

It is, however, possible to do it with `left join` as Ctznkane525 shows in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48646624/390819).

#### Edit

As [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh) pointed out in the comments, `not in` might lead to [surprising results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129077/390819) when there are nulls in the subquery. So, here is the `not exists` version:

```
select Id, Name
from Service s
where not exists (
    select *
    from AssetService a
    where AssetId = 1
    and ServiceId = s.Id);
```

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2344c/11)

Comment: The NOT IN behavior surprise many people when null values are returned from the subquery. That's why I usually do NOT EXISTS instead. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @jarlh That's a new one for me. I just realized I never used `not in` with data sets that contained nulls. So, thanks for teaching me something new today! :)

Comment: Change the "where not in" to "where not exists" as jarlh suggested an it will produce what generally will be a superior query plan to the 'outer join where something is null.' solution.  Specifically, it will produce semi-antijoin, which has been shown generally to outperform outer joins.

Answer (score 35):

You can you use an intelligent left join to return non-matching rows only from left table(Service)

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name FROM [Service] S
LEFT JOIN ServiceAsset SA
ON S.Id = SA.ServiceId
WHERE SA.ServiceId IS NULL
```

[image]

**Note:** INNER JOIN returns the matching rows whereas you want the non matching rows then use LEFT JOIN instead

Comment: I wonder what's going to happen if there's a record in `AssetService` 2 and 3. I updated the table in my question

Comment: then this query will return nothing

Comment: I tested my answer. It will return those service records which are not in AssetService

Comment: Yes, but my question includes `where AssetId = 1`

Comment: Even if you include the AssetId = 1 then there will be nothing because AssetId here doesn't mean (When you want only non-matching service rows)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice. This ought to be the accepted answer.

Comment: The `IS NULL` may at first be misleading to a novice... how can a non-null field be null? Well... because our join is a new table which is a combination of fields from both tables in the join, young paduwan... I seem to have to learn this over and over O.o

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select * from Service where Id not in (
    select ServiceId from AssetService where AssetId = 1 
    -- we have to filter out NULLs, in case of NULL values query result will be empty
    and ServiceId not null
)
```

It doesn't require any `join`.

Here is solution with `join`:

```
select Id, Name from Service
except
select S.Id, S.Name from Service S join AssetService [AS] on S.Id = [AS].ServiceId
where [AS].AssetId = 1
```

Comment: Why does this have +1 but a seemingly identical earlier answer have -1?