# NOT IN based on multiple columns?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbi

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
  p_id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  j_id varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  u_id varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm using the following to find rows based on p_id and j_id:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE p_id = ? AND j_id = ? LIMIT 10
```

I want to extend this query so that it also excludes some rows, for example, I have a list like this:

```
class MyEntity {
    public p_id 
    public j_id;
    public u_id;
}

List<MyEntity> rowsToExclude = new ArrayList<>();
rowsToExclude.add(new MyEntity(1, 3, 5));
rowsToExclude.add(new MyEntity(7, 8, 9));
```

How do I feed the `rowsToExclude` into the query, for example in SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE p_id = ? AND j_id = ?
  and (p_id, j_id, u_id) not in ((?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?))
LIMIT 10
```

I found this reference that was the closest to what I need but not quite:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55921388/12177456

```
handle.createQuery("SELECT value FROM items WHERE kind in (<listOfKinds>)")
      .bindList("listOfKinds", keys)
      .mapTo(String.class)
      .list();

// Or, using the 'vararg' definition
handle.createQuery("SELECT value FROM items WHERE kind in (<varargListOfKinds>)")
      .bindList("varargListOfKinds", "user_name", "docs", "street", "library")
      .mapTo(String.class)
      .list();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select NOT IN multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033604/select-not-in-multiple-columns)

Comment: [Another possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646568/sql-server-join-where-not-exist-on-other-table) - could you load the values you want to exclude into a temp table and exclude them in a join or NOT EXISTS subquery?

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: @Mark I'm using postgres

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to load the entities to exclude into a temp table and do a LEFT JOIN like the one suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48646883/4032703). Something like the following (fair warning: I'm not in front of an IDE so the syntax may not be perfect):

```
SELECT m.*
from mytable m
LEFT JOIN #tmpTbl t
ON m.p_id = t.p_id and m.j_id = t.id and m.u_id = p.u_id
-- t.id is auto-generated
WHERE t.id IS NULL and m.p_id = ? AND m.j_id = ?
```

I'm assuming here that you've created a temp table named `#tmpTbl` (which has an auto-generated ID) and loaded your list of exclusions into it.