# MySQL bug: NOT IN + subquery using GROUP BY HAVING returns nothing

Tags: mysql

I'm querying on this table:

```
SKU
aaaa
bbbb
bbbb
NULL
```

Here's the query:

```
select *
from TEST as N                                      
where  N.SKU NOT IN (select SKU
                     from TEST
                     group by SKU
                     having count(*)>1);
```

I expect the query returns 'aaaa', however, it returns nothing.

The reason I expect that is because the subquery below only returns 'bbbb':

```
select SKU
from TEST
group by SKU
having count(*)>1
```

Therefore, 'aaaa' NOT IN the subquery result.

To show the bug please copy and paste these statements in your MySQL IDE to create schema:

```
drop table if exists TEST;
create table TEST(
SKU varchar(255)
);
insert into TEST values('aaaa'),('bbbb'),('bbbb'),(NULL);
```

Comment: Reproduced in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/769ffa/8

Comment: And for the record SQL Server behaves as one might expect (unless I'm missing something too): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e50d/1

Comment: Ok and so apparently it's something with the NULL in the table. Removing the NULL returns the 'aaaa' row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93efbf/1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/129151/491243

Comment: @lc. thanks for the effort of editing and reproducing in different sql flavors. I was just wondering, since NULL has been discarded by attaching having clause. why does it still affect the final result. very confusing.

Comment: @John Woo subquery doesn't return NULL, so NOT IN is not able to compare against NULL in this case.

Comment: @Shawn No problem and I honestly don't know. Replacing the subquery with a list of string constants `NOT IN ('bbbb')` *does* work, so it's something the optimizer is probably doing internally.

Comment: @lc. True. Maybe the optimizer somehow pulls the having clause out of subquery, that way it returns nothing for sure, but I'm just guessing. I'll keep an eye on this post, see if anyone else will make a follow-up.

Comment: Maybe you could ask https://dba.stackexchange.com/ ; that's an interesting problem.

Comment: @Ring Ø good suggestion. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198945/mysql-bug-not-in-subquery-using-group-by-having-returns-nothing

Answer (score 0):

This works OK, if subquery returns only one row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST as N 
WHERE N.SKU NOT IN (
  CAST((select SKU from TEST group by SKU having count(*)>1) AS CHAR)
)
```

However, if it returns more then 1 row, error will be triggered. Another solution (if the subquery returns more than 1 row):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST as N 
WHERE N.SKU IN (
  (select SKU from TEST group by SKU having count(*) <= 1)
)
```