# Why does NOT IN condition on SQL Server "break" when list includes a NULL value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements, logical-operators

Take these two simple statements:

```
SELECT '1 IS NOT IN THE LIST' WHERE 1 NOT IN (2, 3, 4)
SELECT '1 IS NOT IN THE LIST' WHERE 1 NOT IN (NULL, 2, 3, 4)
```

The results you will get are:

[image]

Basically, as soon as you add NULL to the list, the NOT IN condition always returns FALSE, implying that (in this case) 1 = NULL

Can someone explain why this happens?

Following on from that, why does this statement (the opposite of the NOT IN that returned FALSE) not return TRUE?

```
SELECT '1 IS IN THE LIST' WHERE 1 IN (NULL, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Somebody already give us an answer.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values) regards,
Arnaud

Comment: well covered question.  if you want this behaviour run: set ansi_nulls OFF

Comment: @NickKavadias - terrible advice to be giving in 2018 when Microsoft have been advising for years that they plan to force ansi_nulls ON in a future version of the product and you [should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) "Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature"