# Is "not in" an acceptable clause for this SQL, or is there a more elegant approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the following SQL, `@UserExtendedSecurity` is a table variable which simply provides a 1 or 0 indicator based on whether or not a user has extended security:

```
INSERT INTO @UserExtendedSecurity (UserId, UserName, HasExtendedSecurity)
    SELECT
        ue.Id,
        adu.FirstName + ' ' + adu.LastName,
        0
    FROM 
        UserExtension ue
    JOIN 
        ADUser adu ON ue.ADUserId = adu.Id
    WHERE 
        ue.Id NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM @UserExtendedSecurity)
```

In the SQL example above, `@UserExtendedSecurity` already has all users with `HasExtendedSecurity = 1`, so I'm just selecting the remaining users into the table var with a `HasExtendedSecurity` value of 0. The `NOT IN` clause at the end does what it needs to do but is there a more proper/elegant/efficient approach to accomplish what I'm doing? Do SQL experts consider using `NOT IN` in this way as a red flag?

Comment: I prefer `not exists`, but `not in` is not a "red flag".

Comment: Use `NOT EXISTS` instead! Too many programmers have been surprised by NOT IN's behavior when it comes to null values from the subquery.

Comment: When `UserId` is defined as `NOT NULL` it's safe to use `NOT IN`. But using it against Nullable columns should be avoided and `NOT EXISTS` used instead.

Comment: cool thanks for the tip.  so I can replace "not in" with "not exists" without changing anything else?  this would not create any unexpected side effects (and potentially avoid them) and sql experts would generally consider this better form?

Comment: Compare plans. Most likely it does not matter what to use, as the optimizer since 2012 will choose the best plan.

Comment: simply replacing "not in" with "not exists" doesn't work

Comment: `not exists` requires a co-related subquery. `not in` does not

Answer (score 0):

You will actually get better performance with `NOT EXISTS`, surprisingly. Just be aware the behavior is slightly different-- it works better with null values (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values) for details).

```
INSERT INTO @UserExtendedSecurity
(
    UserId,
    UserName,
    HasExtendedSecurity
)
SELECT
ue.Id,
adu.FirstName + ' ' + adu.LastName,
0
FROM 
UserExtension ue
JOIN ADUser adu ON ue.ADUserId = adu.Id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT 0 FROM @UserExtendedSecurity WHERE UserId = ue.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 3 options:
(lt;dr; - 
All options are valid and all have their correct usage - but In general, I would rather go with `not exists` most of the times.)

### `NOT IN`

```
SELECT
    ue.Id,
    adu.FirstName + ' ' + adu.LastName,
    0
FROM 
    UserExtension AS ue
JOIN 
    ADUser AS adu ON ue.ADUserId = adu.Id
WHERE 
    ue.Id NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM @UserExtendedSecurity)
```

Pros:

1. the select statement from the table variable is not related to the main select.
2. simple, readable syntax.

Cons:

1. `null` handling. When you have a `null` inside a`NOT IN`, you will not get any results, unless [ansi_nulls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) is set to off (which you really should avoid since it's deprecated), since `x NOT IN(y,NULL)` is equivalent to `x <> y and x <> null` - and comparing to any value to `null`, including another `null`, will return `unknown`.
2. With a large set inside the `IN`, performance might be slower compared to other options.

### `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
    ue.Id,
    adu.FirstName + ' ' + adu.LastName,
    0
FROM 
    UserExtension AS ue
JOIN 
    ADUser AS adu ON ue.ADUserId = adu.Id
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @UserExtendedSecurity WHERE UserId = ue.Id)
```

Pros:

1. `Null` is no longer an issue.
2. Better performance than the `not in` alternative.

Cons:

1. A bit more cumbersome syntax.
2. Requires a correlated sub query.

### `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
    ue.Id,
    adu.FirstName + ' ' + adu.LastName,
    0
FROM 
    UserExtension AS ue
JOIN 
    ADUser AS adu ON ue.ADUserId = adu.Id
LEFT JOIN  @UserExtendedSecurity AS ues ON ues.UserId = ue.Id
WHERE ues.UserId IS NULL
```

Pros:

1. No sub query is needed, correlated or not.
2. `Null` values are "naturally" handled.
3. Better performance than the `not in` alternative.

Cons:

1. Might cause duplicate results.
2. The other alternatives conveys the intent of the query better, making this alternative less readable.