# danger about mysql's IN and NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I have read the documents about mysql's `IN` and `NULL`. Look at here:
[Subqueries with ANY, IN, or SOME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)
, [Subqueries with ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html)

I did some experiments.

#### create table(MySQL 5.6)

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO  test(uid) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

#### statement1.1:

```
select 2 union all (select null);
+------+
|      |
+------+
|    2 |
| NULL |
+------+
```

#### statement1.2:

```
select uid from `test` where uid not in (select 2 union all (select null));  
+------+
|      |
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

#### statement1.3:

```
select uid from `test` where 1 not in (select 2 union all (select null));  
+------+
|      |
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

**So far, everything has been done as planned. But now we modify the statement, confusing things happen.**

#### statement2.1:

```
select 2 union all (select null from test);
+------+
|      |
+------+
|   2  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

#### statement2.2:

```
select uid from `test` where uid not in (select 2 union all (select null from test));
+------+
|      |
+------+
|  3   |
+------+
|  4   |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
```

#### statement2.3:

```
select uid from `test` where 1 not in (select 2 union all (select null from test)); 
+------+
|      |
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

#### statement2.4:

```
select uid from `test` where uid not in (select 3 union all (select null from test));
+------+
|      |
+------+
|  2   |
+------+
|  4   |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
```

#### statement2.5:

```
select uid from `test` where 1 not in (select 3 union all (select null from test)); 
+------+
|      |
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

someone can explain the statement2.2, 2.4? The result is inconsistent when we use expression or constant as the operand? And why `1` don't appeared in 2.2 and 2.4's result? It seems that 2.3 and 2.5 should be right as the mysql's document described.

Comment: I edited the first example. Can you edit the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT IN` with subquery that returns `NULL` should always return 0 rows.

Related: [NOT IN clause and NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values).

---

It looks like a bug and it's not reproducible on MySQL 8.0.

Query:

```
select uid from test where uid not in (select 2 union all (select null));
select uid from test where 1 not in (select 2 union all (select null));
select uid from test where uid not in(select 2 union all (select null from test));
select uid from test where uid not in(select 3 union all (select null from test));
select uid from test where 1 not in (select 3 union all (select null from test));
-- 0 rows selected
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cda42ae68393da409fb643d211d2c0e)**

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right. Thank you. MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 have the same problem.