# How do flag the unselected records in a top selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement  I need to choose only a selected number of records from a group.  However, I also need to flag the not choosen records in the even that they will need to be referred to at a later date.

I have over 80K records in Segment 1.  The requirement is to select 50000 records

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET [SuppressionReason] = 'REC LIMIT REACHED - S1'
 WHERE
   [ID] NOT IN 
    (
     SELECT TOP 50000 [ID] FROM mytable
      WHERE segment = '1' 
    );
```

However, this results in 0 records getting labeled in the SuppressionReason field as  'REC LIMIT REACHED - S1'.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You have `where segment = '1'` in the subquery but not in the outer query.  That seems odd.

Comment: Have you checked that `SELECT TOP 50000 [ID] FROM mytable WHERE segment = '1'` returns the results you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, records are returned in just the select statement

Comment: can ID be NULL?  is it the problem similar to 'select 'true' where 3 not in (1, 2, null)'

Comment: And, Gordon, you are correct.  I edited the query to:                                                              UPDATE mytable
   SET [SuppressionReason] = 'REC LIMIT REACHED - S1'
WHERE
    Segment = 1 and [ID] NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT TOP 50000 [ID] FROM mytable
       WHERE segment = '1' 
    );                                                                                                                        But the result is still 0

Comment: No, the ID's are 100% populated

Comment: I recon that SELECT TOP 50000 [ID] FROM mytable
       WHERE segment = '1'  is returning a null somewhere, meaning you select no records - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values

Comment: oh, ok then! have you experimented with select statements to see if records are actually being selected for update?  does  SELECT TOP 50000 [ID] FROM mytable
       WHERE segment = '1'  actually return only a subset of what is in MyTable?

Comment: Is ID unique? Perhaps there are less then 50,000 unique IDs.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Based on testing with the following code, are you absolutely certain that you have more than 50,000 records?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(10),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(10),
    SEGMENT INT,
    SUPPRESSION VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
    (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SEGMENT)
VALUES 
    ('JOHN', 'KRAMER',1),
    ('MATT','GEORGE',1),
    ('PHILIP','MCCAIN',1),
    ('ANDREW','THOMAS',1)

UPDATE #TEMP
    SET SUPPRESSION = 'YEP'
WHERE ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT TOP(2) ID FROM #TEMP WHERE SEGMENT = 1)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

This produces the following output, which I suspect is exactly what you are expecting to get.

```
   1    JOHN    KRAMER  1   NULL
   2    MATT    GEORGE  1   NULL
   3    PHILIP  MCCAIN  1   YEP
   4    ANDREW  THOMAS  1   YEP
```