# Why result set is EMPTY when the NOT IN inner query contains value 'NULL'?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my mysql table named `samp`

```
+--------+--------+
| name   | roleid |
+--------+--------+
| alki   |      2 |
| karthi |      3 |
| aadhil |      2 |
| pri    |      2 |
| pri    |      2 |
+--------+--------+
```

when I used query like `select name from samp where name not in ('alki','pri',NULL)`

I expected the result to be,

```
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| karthi |
| aadhil |
+--------+
```

But my result is `Empty set`. I have an alternative to do this. But I need to know the reason behind this.

Comment: What's the result when the query is `select name from samp where name not in ('alki','pri')` ?

Comment: FYI, you could refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values

Comment: am getting my expected result. But what if the inner query returns a result that includes 'NULL'?

Comment: Take a look at the link that @Pham X. Bach provided. It gives an excellent explanation of why you're getting the results you're getting. This is a common problem, and comes from not understanding how NULL works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below

```
select name from samp where name not in ('alki','pri') and name is not null
```

Comment: yes. It will work. But why including just `NULL` makes my result Empty. I need to know what's happening there.

Comment: First of all NULL is not a value it's marker for showing empty  and that's why whenever you need to compare with NULL value you need to use is null or is not null @PRIYAM

Comment: As fa06 says, `[name] = NULL` check will always be false, as will `[name]<>NULL` check, because you can't compare with NULL, so it is messing up your logic.

What if you did `SELECT name FROM samp where NAME not in (sub query) OR (0 = (SELECT count(1) FROM (subquery))`  (Hopefully that makes sense, without the detail of your subquery it is hard to be more specific)

Comment: @PRIYAM I repeat, the link that was given you above will explain the answer to your question in detail. So, if you need to know what's happening there, please go and read it. The actual value that expressions involving null (besides `IS NULL`) will return is `UNKNOWN` which usually evaluates to false.

Comment: @BobRodes yes, the link helped me in detail.. I understood what's exactly happening.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` means unknown it isn't a value, you need to use `not null` instead of use in `NULL`

You can try this.

```
select name from samp where name not in ('alki','pri') and name is not null
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
select name
from samp
where name not in ('alki', 'pri');
```

`NULL` fails `not in`, just as it fails most other comparisons.

If you explicitly wanted to include `NULL`, you would need to include it as:

```
select name
from samp
where name not in ('alki', 'pri') or name is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how `NULL` is meant to behave. It doesn't compare with anything by design. Your query is interpreted like:

```
select name
from samp
where name <> 'alki'
and name <> 'pri'
and name <> NULL
```

Since `name` neither equals not "not" equal `NULL` the condition is not met.