# Impossible row counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I don't know how does MySQL works internally, but I'm sure there are some problem with indexes or some metainformation about table counts:

```
mysql> select count(*) from Event;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     5925 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from Event where event_id in (select discount_event_id from Discount);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     5901 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,12 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from Event where event_id not in (select discount_event_id from Discount);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,11 sec)
```

These `24` missing `event_id`s makes no sense. It's just logically impossible from my point of view. There cannot be `24` rows that both are and aren't in another set. Or they are, or they aren't.

Also, as suggested from some of the answers and comments, there are no `NULL` `event_id`s, since these are the *rowids*:

```
mysql> select count(*) from Event where event_id is null;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

What is going on?

Comment: 24 are those that are `null`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values (though that's about SQL Server it's very likely to fit here too)

Comment: Try `SELECT COUNT(*), event_id FROM Event GROUP BY event_id WITH ROLLUP` to get a breakdown.

Comment: Looks like you're checking the wrong table/column for `NULL`s. Try: `SELECT discount_event_id FROM discount WHERE discount_event_id IS NULL;`

Comment: @stickybit Yeah, I just found the same. Write it as answer and I'll mark it as the valid one.

Answer (score 4):

It means there are 24 `event_id` that are `NULL`

```
select count(*) from Event where event_id IS NULL
```

both `in` and `not in` operators return `NULL` when you compare with `NULL` value, which is coerced to `FALSE` hence omitted from both result sets.

Comment: There'are no `NULL` `event_id`s since that field is the rowid of the `Event` table. See the update on the question.