# The NOT IN with NULL values dilemma in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-in

When I used this code

```
WHEN col1 NOT IN (SELECT col2 FROM table_name) THEN 'something'
```

it didn't give the expected results knowing that col2 contains a NULL value, Why did this happened ? Does using IN with NULL values messes with data stored in memory or what?

Comment: In SQL, `NULL` does not compare with anything else. That's why we have `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Please refer this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause

Comment: Thanks a lot It really helped me a lot.

Comment: You ask if IN with NULL values messes with (something). I hope from this experience you will not form the wrong impression, which many developers seem to hold, that IN doesn't work if the "in list" may contain NULL. That is **only** a problem for the **NOT** IN condition; it is not a problem for the **IN** condition. Then: besides using NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN, as Gordon Linnoff has shown, a different solution (simpler in my opinion) is to use `when col1 not in (select col2 from table_name WHERE COL2 IS NOT NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy for the great clarification I actually had that impression that the problem with `IN` in general. Many thanks! Actually that's what I did by adding the `WHERE` Clause and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not an issue with Oracle.  This is how SQL is defined.

When the subquery returns a `NULL` value with `NOT IN`, then no rows match at all.  For this reason, I strongly recommend *always* using `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bst WHERE x.n = bst.p)
     THEN 'Leaf'
```

As a corollary, I usually use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, even though it does not have this problem.

Why does this occur?  `NULL` means that the value is *unknown*, not that the value is "missing" or something else.

So, if all the elements have values, this is easy to calculate:

```
1 NOT IN (1, 2)  --> false
3 NOT IN (1, 2)  --> true
```

However:

```
1 NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)  --> false 
3 NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)  --> NULL, because NULL could be equal to "3"
```

Basically, if *any* value is `NULL`, then `NOT IN` returns either "false" or `NULL`.  Both "false" and `NULL` are treated the same in `WHEN` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extremely fast answer it really solved a lot of puzzles in my head, also with @Suresh Gajera 's link [NULL values inside NOT IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause) I got the full mystery solved thanks alot