# NOT IN is not working as expected for string column type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I found something weird between NOT IN and IN where I use a string type column. It works fine for IN but not for NOT IN. Though both works (NOT IN and IN) for integer type column

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 where t1.email not in (select t2.email from `table2` t2)
```

doesn't return any result from t1 which exist in t2 though it should as there are eligible records whereas

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 where t1.email in (select t2.email from `table2` t2)
```

returns the records from t1 which are in t2.

Comment: Are you sure that you have records with emails in `table 1` which does not exist in `table 2`

Comment: thing to notes when working with string, always make sure the string is as expected. Based on my experience, this kind of issue occurred because of "spaces" or whitespace in the string that rendered it to be different.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco yes

Comment: @user_387909 can you post `test` data from both tables?

Comment: @ariefbayu yeah there is no spaces or whitespace.

Comment: also make sure that the collations are what you expect, specifically matching case insensitivity.

Comment: Modifying query to below worked.

**SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 where t1.email not in (select t2.email from `table2` t2 where t2.email is not null)**

Since table2's email column value was NULL for one row which was returning no records. But I am not sure the reason behind NULL causing the problem.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco While I was working on to provide you the sample data I found the issue was because of NULL.

Comment: Awesome :).........

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Do you know what is causing to not return any result in presence of NULL ?

Comment: I guess this is the response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause

Comment: When ansi_nulls is on, 3 <> null is UNKNOWN, so the predicate evaluates to UNKNOWN, and you don't get any rows.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example to explains this appearance which also occurs in other DBMS like SQL Server and Oracle.

Assume that

```
select t2.email from `table2` t2
```

returns

```
+-------------+
| email       |
+-------------+
| 111@abc.com |
| 222@abc.com |
| NULL        |
+-------------+
```

When execute

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 where t1.email not in (select t2.email from `table2` t2)
```

MySQL translates it into

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 
where 
t1.email <> '111@abc.com' AND t1.email <> '222@abc.com' AND t1.email <> NULL
```

The `where` clause always returns `NULL` because any value compare to `NULL` returns `NULL` and any boolean value do `AND` operation with `NULL` also returns `NULL`. Therefore, the whole SQL query as shown above always return non record.

Similarly,

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 where t1.email in (select t2.email from `table2` t2)
```

will be translated into

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 
where 
t1.email = '111@abc.com' OR t1.email = '222@abc.com' OR t1.email <> NULL
```

The value of `t1.email <> NULL` is `NULL`, which will be ignored if any other comparation is `TRUE`.

Comment: In your 2nd sql, did you wanted to write **SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 where t1.email in (select t2.email from `table2` t2)** ?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying query to below worked.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1 
 WHERE t1.email NOT IN ( SELECT t2.email 
                           FROM table2 t2 
                          WHERE t2.email IS NOT NULL )
```

Since table2's email column value was `NULL` for one row which was returning no records.

Comment: Alternatively, you'd convert `SELECT t2.email` to `SELECT COALESCE(t2.email,' ')` while removing `WHERE t2.email IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan That is right. But is there any difference between COALESCE and t2.email IS NOT NULL in respect to performance ?

Comment: Yes, also I don't think that would impact the performance as long as `NOT IN` is used. Perhaps `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0
                     FROM table2 t2 
                    WHERE COALESCE(t2.email,' ') = t1.email )` would be able to impact positively.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NOT IN` with subqueries.  The reason is simple:  it does not handle `NULL` values as a person would expect them to be handled.

Instead, just get used to using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table1` t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM `table2` t2
                  WHERE t1.email= t2.email 
                 ) ;
```

Why does this not work as expected?  This is because of how SQL defines `NULL` values.  They have the semantics of an "unknown" value rather than a "missing" value.

Consider the following conditions:

- `1 IN (1, 2)`              -- evaluates to true
- `3 IN (1, 2)`              -- evaluates to false

`NULL`s do not affect this, because it is an exact match:

- `1 IN (1, 2, NULL)`       -- evaluates to true
- `3 IN (1, 2, NULL)`       -- evaluates to NULL, which is treated as false

But `NULL`s do affect `NOT IN`

- `1 NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)`   -- evaluates to false
- `3 NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)`   -- evaluates to NULL because NULL is "unknown"

The key is that `NULL` does not have a specific meaning -- it means "unknown".  So, `NULL` *could* be equal to 3.  Hence, the result of the last expression is "unknown" (i.e. `NULL`) rather than "true".