# SQL counts not adding up when using 'NOT IN' and 'IN' clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have two tables, T1 and T2, which have some records in common. I am trying to find out which records are shared between the two. Just to clarify, the 'msg' is unique to each record.

T1 has ~1.4 million records. When I run

```
select count(*) from T1 where msg in (select msg from T2)
```

I get ~950,000 records. Ok, 950k out of 1.4 million. There should be around 450k records that show up when I run the inverse right? Query below:

```
select count(*) from T1 where msg not in (select msg from T2)
```

This query actually returns 0. How is that possible? Furthermore when I run

```
select count(*) from T1 where id not in (select id from T2)
```

I get about 1100 records, so there are obviously some records in T1 which aren't in T2.

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, fully qualify all your column references with the table name since both tables share a column name - you want to be 100% sure that SQL Server is using the correct column. Secondly is `msg` ever null?

Comment: What is the type of `msg` column in both tables? Is it nullable?

Answer (score 2):

You're facing **NULL values inside NOT IN clause** problem.

You should do something like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
```

[SET ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Specifies ISO compliant behavior of the Equals (=) and Not Equal To
>   (<>) comparison operators when they are used with null values in SQL
>   Server 2019 (15.x).

Read the following thread to have a better understanding.

[NULL values inside NOT IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause)

Answer (score 2):

**Always go for NOT EXISTS clause, instead of NOT IN.**

> The reason is, even if one NULL value is present in the subquery, SQL
>   Server returns 0 rows, because NOT IN will not match any rows.

```sql
select count(*) from T1 where msg not in (select msg from T2)
```

is equivalent to

```sql
select count(*) from T1 
WHERE (
msg != (SELECT msg FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)
AND
msg!= (SELECT msg FROM t2 WHERE ID=2)
.
.
.
msg!= (SELECT msg FROM t2 WHERE ID=SomeBigNumber)
)
```

[Read more on NOT IN Vs NOT EXISTS](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/)

So, Please modify your query from

```sql
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE msg NOT IN (select msg from T2);
```

to

```sql
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from T2 WHERE T2.msg=T1.msg);
```

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44a09/2). Please refer the same.