# NOT IN filter out NULL values

Tags: sql-server, null, notin

I was trying to filter out some predefined values from a table `sample` which has two column `col1` and `col2`.

My query:

```
select *
from sample
where (col1 is not null or col2 is not null)
and col1 not in (1,2)
and col2 not in (3,4);
```

However, the above query filter out all the null values (in col1 or col2 ).

Example: the below row is filtered out,

```
col1 col2
---------
7 null
null 8
```

I get the expected result when i modify the query to below.

```
select *
from sample
where (col1 is not null or col2 is not null)
and (col1 not in (1,2) or col1 is null)
and (col2 not in (3,4) or col2 is null);
```

Why `NOT IN` filters out rows with `NULL` value even though I am not specified `NULL` in `NOT IN` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
select *
from sample
where (col1 is not null or col2 is not null)
and col1 not in (1,2)
and col2 not in (3,4);
```

ANSI NULL ON/OFF:
This option specifies the setting for ANSI NULL comparisons. When this is on, any query that compares a value with a null returns a 0. When off, any query that compares a value with a null returns a null value ([https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/05/sql-server-quoted_identifier-onoff-and-ansi_null-onoff-explanation/#:~:text=ANSI%20NULL%20ON%2FOFF%3A,null%20returns%20a%20null%20value.](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/05/sql-server-quoted_identifier-onoff-and-ansi_null-onoff-explanation/#:%7E:text=ANSI%20NULL%20ON%2FOFF%3A,null%20returns%20a%20null%20value.)).

this discussed in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause#:~:text=NOT%20IN%20returns%200%20records,not%20the%20value%20being%20tested.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause#:%7E:text=NOT%20IN%20returns%200%20records,not%20the%20value%20being%20tested.)

Comment: Not a great [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is equal to `NULL`, and is anything not equal to `NULL`. For an expression like `NULL NOT IN (1,2)`, this evaluates to *unknown* which (importantly) is **not** true; meaning that the `WHERE` is not met. This is why your second query, where you handle your `NULL`s works.

Alternatively, you could use an `EXISTS`. It's perhaps not an intuitive, but handles `NULL` values:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(7,NULL),(NULL,8))V(col1,col2))
SELECT *
FROM VTE
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 WHERE Col1 IN (1,2)
                   AND Col2 IN (3,4));
```