# Using null inside an operator array for a sequelize query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to simplify the following query (as shown in the docs):

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
User.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.not]: [
      { email: '' },
      { email: null }
    ]
  }
});
```

to

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
User.findAll({
  where: {
    email: {
      [Op.not]: ['', null]
    }
  }
});
```

However, the two queries do not yield the same result. The latter yields an empty array. How can this be?

Comment: Try changing null to some value and if it's work, check this one out.   https://stackoverflow.com/q/129077/2956135

Comment: also the first one you are putting 2 objects in `[Op.not]` which by default it makes AND query.  `NOT (email = '' AND email IS NULL)`.   Do you meant to have OR query? `NOT (email = '' OR email IS NULL)`?

Comment: Let’s say the email is an empty string. That would give: 
`NOT(true AND false) = NOT(false) = TRUE`. This explains why I get a full array with the first one. So you are right, for what I am trying to achieve I should be using an OR. Still strange that these two do not yield the same result though (when the first one is just a simplification of the second one)

Comment: The first one yields to `NOT (email = '' AND/OR email IS NULL)` but the second one yields to `NOT IN ('', NULL)`.  And the second syntax gives you empty result due to "null in NOT IN".  The link I posted above has good explanation of this behavior. To avoid this, you can stick with the first syntax or if your DB has `ansi_nulls` option, you can look into turning this off.