# MS SQL handling null values same as strange string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view **V_BaseData_Extract**  in MS SQL server with one column **Comments** having null values as well having other textual values too. Column type is **nvarcahr**.

What's happening is that SQL returning same count for both below mentioned queries.

**First Query:**

```
select count(*)
  from V_BaseData_Extract where Comments 
  not in  ( '                                                                                                                                                                                               ' , '                                                                                                                               
                                                                  ')
```

**Second Query:**

```
  select count(1) from V_BaseData_Extract a where a.Comments is not null
```

Its handling **null** same as the string mentioned in my **first query's where condition**. What could be the reason behind that ? Am I missing something ?

Is null equivalent to some number of blank spaces ?

Comment: Also try `... where Comments in  ( ' ...`

Comment: That's not working. Its working with NOT only.

Comment: Almost any comparison to `NULL` -- typically including `in` and `not in` return `NULL` when a `NULL` value is involved.

Comment: I *assume* you have no rows where the value of `Comments` is a 0 length string, or entirely made up of white spaces; so the counts are the same.

Comment: Not working? Returns 0 I suppose.

Comment: @Larnu, Why would the count be same ? Null value rows should be returned in `first query` since I'm not `excluding null values` in where clause.

Comment: *"null value rows should be returned in first query since I'm not excluding null values in where clause. "* Yes you are. `NULL NOT IN ('')` = Unknown != True. If you wanted `NULL` values you would need `NOT IN ('') OR Comments IS NULL`

Comment: You simply have no empty strings stored. You can count all values either using IS NOT NULL, or using NOT IN ('   ').

Comment: @jarlh I can count using both conditions, but I would like to know why null values were not returned in first query.

Comment: _null_ NOT IN (' ') evaluates to null, but only true is passed to count().

Comment: @jarlh Technically it's called `UNKNOWN`, but yes, `WHERE` only passes predicates that are `TRUE` and not `UNKNOWN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct explanation. Comments above helped me look into right direction and search relevant terms.

[NULL values inside NOT IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause)