# How to use NOT IN in binary tree problem using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I am trying to solve this problem,

> You are given a table, BST, containing two columns: N and P,  where N
> represents the value of a node in Binary Tree, and P is the parent of
> N.
>
> Write a query to find the node type of Binary Tree ordered by the
> value of the node. Output one of the following for each node:
>
> ```
> Root: If node is root node.
> Leaf: If node is leaf node.
> Inner: If node is neither root nor leaf node.
> ```

**Input**:

[image]

**Desired Output**:

```
1 Leaf
2 Inner
3 Leaf
5 Root
6 Leaf
8 Inner
9 Leaf
```

This is my query, can anyone tell me why it's not working?

```
select case
            when P is NULL then CONCAT_WS(" ", N, 'Root')
            when N not in (SELECT DISTINCT P FROM BST) then CONCAT_WS(" ", N, 'Leaf')
            else CONCAT_WS(" ", N, 'Inner')
        end
from BST ORDER BY N ASC;
```

Comment: @Akina I have updated the question. Sorry

Comment: Well. The task does not need in WHERE IN. CASE with EXISTS is enough.

Comment: @Akina Why is my query not working? I implemented the logic according to their problem statement.

Comment: @Akina Why is `NOT IN` function not working in my case for leaf node?

Comment: Because of NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `NULL` inside the `P` column in which case an expression such as:

```
1 NOT IN (NULL, 2, 8, 5)
```

will return `unknown` instead of the "expected" result `true` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause)).

The solution is to make a subtle change like so:

```
N NOT IN (SELECT P FROM BST WHERE P IS NOT NULL)
```

Or use an `EXISTS` query:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BST AS bst2 WHERE bst2.P = bst.N)
```

Comment: So if I have NULL then `NOT IN` won't work ? If I have NULL will `IN` works?

Comment: Additional clarification... `1 IN (null, 1)` returns true, `2 IN (null, 1)` returns unknown, so this kind of produces the _expected_ result when used inside WHERE/WHEN clause. But `1 NOT IN (null, 2)` returns unknown where you would be _expecting_ true since 1 does not exist in the set.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT n,
       ELT((1 + (2 * (t1.p IS NULL)) + (EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM BST t2 WHERE t1.n=t2.p))), 'Leaf', 'Inner', 'Single', 'Root') type
FROM BST t1
ORDER BY n;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=287b1de2b2bb532d73619c19bcf8a86b

I add one more option 'Single' - the case when the node is root and leaf at the same time (node 4 in my fiddle).

Comment: Thank you for this approach. Can you break the query down and explain how its working, I  am not able to understand it

Comment: @user_12 `t1.p IS NULL` checks does the node is a root (R, can be 0 or 1). `EXISTS` checks does the node is a leaf (L, can be 0 or 1). Then I calculate `1 + 2*R + L` which can be from 1 to 4. `ELT` selects according value by this calculated expression. That's all. PS. EXISTS with correlated subquery is more fast then WHERE IN in most cases (of course suitable index must present).