# Unexpected behaviour in MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

The table 'employees' from the dataset classicmodels https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx has two relevant fields: employeeNumber and reportsTo (direct boss of each employee)

I'm trying to get all employees that are not bosses (they aren't the "reportsTo" of any employee). What I'm trying is:

```
select employeeNumber from employees
where employeeNumber not in (
    select distinct reportsTo
    from employees
);
```

But it returns empty set

I don't understand whats happening here. If I invert the condition it works:

```
select employeeNumber from employees
where employeeNumber in (
    select distinct reportsTo
    from employees
);
```

This query returns the employees who are bosses of someone. I've already tried using different alias for both tables.

**More information**

- Table definition

  ```
   CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeNumber` int NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Employees direct superior',
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`),
  KEY `reportsTo` (`reportsTo`),
  KEY `officeCode` (`officeCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reportsTo`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`)
  ```

  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
- Explain
  [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NULL values inside NOT IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause)  However, to address your need: short answer use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` to handle the null situations. This is expected behavior of "NOT IN"; no need to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Or add to the subquery `select distinct reportsTo
    from employees
    where reportsTo is not null`