# Both sqlite not in and not exists clause are not returning any data when I use different column names as criteria

Tags: excel, sqlite, xlwings

I'm using the  XLWINGS add-on for Excel in order to use SQL directly inside of Excel. (XLWINGS is a Python add-on that uses SQLite for queries.)

I'm analyzing a table of approximately 20,000 records downloaded from iNaturalist. My goal is to show which species "emerge" in a certain month of the year.

Using SQL I create table B which shows which species have been observed in previous months. I then do a second query to find which species have been observed during the month I'm examining but which don't exist in table B.

For example to show species emerging in May, the first query selects all observations for January, March and April. The second query should show all species observed in May but not found in Table B.

All of this worked when I used the following code to create table B

`select distinct species  from a where month <5 and species !=''`

And the following code to get the final results:

`select taxonomy,scientific_name, species, common_name,  date, image_url, id  from a where month = 5 and  species not in (select species from b) order by taxonomy, species, Month_day`

I need to change this to use "scientific_name" instead of "species" to get more meaningful results. Both 'species' and "scientific_name" are text data types in Excel, but the second query does not produce any output after the change.

In the following I just changed 'species' to 'scientific_name' for both Select statements. The first query works for table B, but the second one below doesn't produce any output:

`select taxonomy,scientific_name, species, common_name,  date, image_url, id  from a where month = 5 and  scientific_name not in (select scientific_name from b)  order by taxonomy, scientific_name, Month_day, species`

I also tried the following which didn't work either:

`select taxonomy, scientific_name, species, common_name, date, image_url,id from a where month = 5 and not exists (select 1 from b where scientific_name = b.scientific_name) order by taxonomy, scientific_name, Month_day`

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If table B has rows where `scientific_name` is NULL, then the expression not in `(select scientific_name from b)` will always be FALSE, due to the three valued logic of NULL.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause)

The other version with not exists would be correct, but you need to compare `a.scientific_name = b.scientific_name`

```
select taxonomy, scientific_name, species, common_name, date, image_url,id 
from a where month = 5 
and not exists (select 1 from b where a.scientific_name = b.scientific_name) 
order by taxonomy, scientific_name, Month_day
```