# BigQuery: NOT IN (subquery) filtering out everything from main query

Tags: google-bigquery

In this query I am trying to return the number of Contract IDs if it does not exist in the results of another subquery using NOT IN with a common key created using CONCAT() statement to eliminate the duplicated records between new and legacy data sources.

The query was working last month but have suddenly gone off. The problem can be resolved by rewriting the logic but it would be very helpful to know why NOT IN had stopped working?

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
   CONTRACT_ID,
   STORE_ID,
   ITEM_ID,
   INV

FROM NEW_DATA_SOURCE

WHERE
   CONCAT(CONTRACT_ID,STORE_ID) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(CONTRACT_NBR,STORE_NBR) FROM OLD_DATA_SOURCE)
```

[FIX 1] I am trying to contain the results from the subquery after NOT IN with an Array and see if NOT IN works well with it.

**[FIX 2]** Rewriting the NOT IN statement as a LEFT OUTER JOIN then exclude common records using a flag have solved my issue, but some explanation would be needed as NOT IN is a very common clause and would like to know what's going on with it.

The main query contains about 10 million records
while the subquery contains about 4 millions records.

So, in the most extreme case, the main query should return at least 6 million record but it is returning NO RECORDS.

Comment: Do you have any `NULL` value in `OLD_DATA_SOURCE` for columns `CONTRACT_NBR` or `STORE_NBR`? `CONCAT()` will return `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`, and `NOT IN` won't return any rows if there's a `NULL` value in the subquery (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/129077/2650437 for more info on this).

Comment: I just went back and checked, there is actually 1 NULL  concat-ed result from the OLD_Data_Source. I thought NOT IN would process it like this: 'contract01store01' not in (null,  'contract02store01'), and therefore still returns  'contract01store01'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause. BigQuery uses ANSI SQL handling of NULLs. The simplest fix is to filter out NULLs in the sub-select query, using IS NOT NULL clause.