# Understanding SQL NOT IN behavior with nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 databases (Database A, Database B) with two tables (table_a, table_b) that I'm trying to reconcile.

I can query Database B using a 3rd party read only ODBC connection which also happens to be very slow.

I want to generate a list of rows in table B that do not exist in table A. Ultimately I want to insert this missing data into A.

To make things quicker/easier on myself (hopefully) I'm running a SQL Server Express. It has Database A and B configured as linked servers. I've done a `SELECT INTO` from Database A into table_a_copy, likewise from Database B into table_b_copy.

Where I'm running into trouble is that the columns I'm using as a key for comparison have different collations between the copied tables.

table_a_copy has collation Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS,
table_b_copy has collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

My initial attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b_copy
WHERE key_b NOT IN (SELECT key_a FROM table_a_copy)
```

Error received:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

My second attempt, trying to resolve collation error:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b_copy
WHERE key_b COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT IN (
  SELECT key_a FROM table_a_copy
)
```

This returned zero results. I *know* not all of table_b rows exists in table_a. To sanity check, I filtered out one of the rows in table_a_copy where key_a was a value I knew existed in both key_a and key_b. I should get at least this 1 row returned:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b_copy
WHERE key_b COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT IN (
  SELECT key_a
  FROM table_a_copy
  WHERE key_a <> 'some value'
)
```

Surprisingly, this returned the row with key_a = 'some value' in addition to all of the other rows I expected.

Just to see what would happen, I tried the same query but instead checking if key_a was not null:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b_copy
WHERE key_b COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT IN (
  SELECT key_a
  FROM table_a_copy
  WHERE key_a IS NOT NULL
)
```

This returned the rows I wanted and expected to see.
My question is WHY does comparing key_a to a value or checking if its null in the subquery cause the NOT IN clause to work as I expect it to?

Comment: Seriously, remove all the text, it doesn't help our understanding, and instead provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results and a DBFiddle ideally.

Comment: Oh, yeah, your actual question is the final query, the rest isn't required. And the case of `null` in `not in` has been asked and answered 100's of times before.

Comment: Here is a non SO answer https://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-not-in-operator-with-null-values/

Comment: Another reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/null-values-inside-not-in-clause

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for this! I was unaware of DBFiddle until now, I'll take advantage of it in the future. Some of my projects use MySQL and sqlite3. I didn't see an option to test MSSQL. I made a bad assumption that my key_a values did not contain a null value. I just checked and it does have a row with a null id. I'm was still not clear on why filtering table_a_copy key_a <> 'some value' also returns the rows I need. I ran subquery separately and discovered key_a <> 'some value' filters NULLs as well.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV- - SQL Server?

Comment: The 2 linked duplicates go through how null compares work in great detail, and link to other articles. If after reading them you are still unsure, create a *minimal* example and ask a new question. Simply put though, null is the absence of a value and as such cannot be equal or not equal.

Comment: @DaleK I've actually run across this problem before apparently as I had already upvoted one of the linked duplicates. I guess I was led astray thinking it was some sort of collation issue, which is why I included all the extraneous backstory.  I didn't even consider the possibility that my table_a data might contain a null key_a. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pete - Although it might be buried deep in the answers on the linked questions, I think you may find your answer with `EXCEPT`. You can run a query `SELECT col1, col2 FROM SourceA EXCEPT SELECT col1, col2 FROM SourceB` along with the reverse to find differences. This treats NULL values like any other and supports multiple columsn in one query. You will still need to tweak this for collation differences. Also note that `EXCEPT` eliinates/ignores duplicates.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MOS0UAy9) for a demo.